# Trigger function updates all rows instead of one

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

I have table "**orders**" and I want to change column "**order_status**" automatically when I add a value in column "**tracking_code**" (default value is null) but my trigger function changes all rows in column "**order_status**" I tried to change if statement in the function, but I hadn't any success. please help me with this question!
this is my table "**orders**":

```
id | order_status_id | tracking_code
----+-----------------+---------------
 12 |               2 | 123456
  9 |               2 |
  6 |               2 |
  7 |               2 |
 10 |               2 |
  8 |               2 |
 11 |               2 |
```

and table "**order_statuses**":

```
 id |   status
----+-------------
  1 | QUEUE
  2 | IN_PROGRESS
  3 | IN_DELIVERY
  4 | DELIVERED
  5 | CANCELED
  6 | RETURNED
```

this is my **trigger** and **function**:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION status_function() RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE public.orders SET order_status_id = public.order_statuses.id
    FROM public.order_statuses
    WHERE status = 'IN_DELIVERY';
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION status_update() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (old.tracking_code != new.tracking_code) THEN
        PERFORM status_function();
        RETURN new;
    ELSE
        RETURN old;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER change_status
    AFTER UPDATE
        OF tracking_code
    ON orders
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE status_update();
```

Comment: Your `status_function()` is an unconditional update to `orders`.

Comment: I know that my fault in status_function! but could you please clarify your answer?

Comment: There is no restriction to the update.  It will update all rows in `orders` to `order_status_id = 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the updated order id to the `status_function`:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION status_function(bigint) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE public.orders SET order_status_id = public.order_statuses.id
    FROM public.order_statuses
    WHERE status = 'IN_DELIVERY' AND public.orders.id = $1;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then, in the `status_update`:

```
PERFORM status_function(old.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like this to restrict the update to only the current row:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION status_function(_id int) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE public.orders SET order_status_id = public.order_statuses.id
      FROM public.order_statuses
     WHERE status = 'IN_DELIVERY'
       AND id = _id;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION status_update() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (old.tracking_code != new.tracking_code) THEN
        PERFORM status_function(old.id);
        RETURN new;
    ELSE
        RETURN old;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```